# Cannot install clang 6 on arch linux

Tags: package-management, pacman

```
pacman -S clang
```

shows me version clang-5.0.0-1

and then install clang-5.0.0-1-x86_64

What kind of magic do I need to perform to install clang in version 6?

Performing `pacman -Syu clang` doesn't help (clang 5 is already installed).

Output from a command:

```
[root@27a829640c2f user]# pacman -Syu clang
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
warning: clang-5.0.0-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) clang-5.0.0-1

Total Installed Size:  273.41 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:        0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&arch=x86_64&repo=Extra&q=clang&maintainer=&flagged= shows version 6.

Comment: `pacman -Syu clang`

Comment: @jasonwryan performed, didn't help

Comment: post your repo config

Comment: Was this accidentally flagged as "off topic"? I don't see any evidence yet that the problem has gone away.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Trolls on the prowl.

Comment: I don't have clang installed, but when trying to install, v 6.0.0-1 is the candidate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is an updated version of a package in the repositories and pacman can't find it, there are one of three issues.

1. Your local database is out-of-sync with the mirror, so you have to fix that with `pacman -Syu`.
2. The mirror(s) that you are syncing with are out of date. So you have to find and configure [up-to-date mirrors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mirrors#Fetching_and_ranking_a_live_mirror_list).
3. The package is in a repo that you haven't enabled in your `pacman.conf`.

Comment: Follow-up: you could also download the package directly from https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/clang/download/ if your mirror happens to be out of date and you don't want to switch it.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, updating mirrorlist fixed an issue.